# Codeigniter ajax live search odd even issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, autocomplete

I have been trying to show suggestion for search key words but it does not show any suggestions. And the meantime I have used search form button to submit the search keywords to show results on another page. And that search button is working but suggestions are not loading somehow.

This is my controller:

```
public function autocomplete() {
        $this->load->model('Search');
        $keyword = $this->input->post('s_keywords');
        $data = $this->Search->getrow($keyword);        
        echo json_encode($data);        
    }
```

this is my model:

```
public function getrow($keyword){            
            $this->db->select('n_id, n_title, n_date, n_description');
            $this->db->like('n_title',$keyword, 'after');
            return $this->db->get('tbl_news')->result_array();
        }
```

this is my view:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="POST" action=" <?php echo base_url() .'index.php/galle/search' ?>">
                    <div class="form-group input-group" id="search_bar" style="">
                        <input id="s_keywords" name="s_keywords" type="text" class="form-control search_bar" placeholder="Search for..."  autocomplete="off">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu txtcountry" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu"  id="DropdownCountry"></ul>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button id="search_key" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Javascript (main.js):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#s_keywords").keyup(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/site_new/index.php/galle/autocomplete",
            data: {
                keyword: $("#s_keywords").val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#DropdownCountry').empty();
                    $('#s_keywords').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                    $('#DropdownCountry').dropdown('toggle');
                }
                else if (data.length == 0) {
                    $('#s_keywords').attr("data-toggle", "");
                }
                $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                    if (data.length >= 0)
                        $('#DropdownCountry').append('<li role="presentation" >' + value['n_title'] + '</li>');
                    //$('#DropdownCountry').append('<li role="presentation" ><a role="menuitem dropdownnameli" class="dropdownlivalue">' + value['n_title'] + '</a></li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
    $('ul.txtcountry').on('click', 'li a', function () {
        $('#s_keywords').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

**UPDATE 1**

Now I'm getting the all the column data instead of search keyword suggestions, how do I get suggestions according to the keywords

**UPDATE 2**

Suggestions are appears only when I put odd keywords eg: a, abc and that doesn't work when I put ab, abcd like even keywords

Comment: any error display in browser console?

Comment: Where are you calling the function `autocomplete` that you defined in the controller?

Comment: wont it execute with the keyup?

Comment: Nishit Maheta, nothing is showing

Comment: is your browser console shows the 200 Response code?

Comment: sometimes 304 sometimes 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function autocomplete() {
    $this->load->model('Search');
    $keyword = $this->input->post('s_keywords');
    $data = $this->Search->getrow($keyword);        
    echo json_encode($data);        
}
```

shouldn't $keyword should be like these $keyword = $this->input->post('**keyword**');
In view after success in ajax call, I would love to have

```
 success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) { 
                $('#DropdownCountry').empty();
                $('#s_keywords').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                $('#DropdownCountry').dropdown('toggle');
               $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                if (data.length >= 0)
                    $('#DropdownCountry').append('<li role="presentation" >' + value['n_title'] + '</li>');
                //$('#DropdownCountry').append('<li role="presentation" ><a role="menuitem dropdownnameli" class="dropdownlivalue">' + value['n_title'] + '</a></li>');
        });

            }
            else if (data.length == 0) {
                $('#s_keywords').attr("data-toggle", "");
            }
    }
```

Comment: many thanks, but there is problem, suggestions are appears only when i put odd number of keyword eg:  i, icc  and it doesn't work when i put sa, sang

Comment: what are you not able to append all <li> in <ul >, I guess?

Comment: no its just appends and shows results but it works only when put keywords which are lengths odd number like a, abc, abcde, and not working when ab, abcd

Comment: yeah its really odd cant fix that, no idea whatsoever